# Помогите с пунктуацией в предложении с двоеточием и запятыми

Tags: пунктуация

Правильная ли пунктуация в следующем предложении?

Если есть следствие в виде: x есть y, вследствие z, то формируется новое следствие за счет такого замещения: x не z, вследствие не y.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот корректная пунктуация:

**Если есть следствие вида "x есть (это) y, *благодаря* z", то формируется новое следствие вида "x не z, следовательно не y".**

Никогда не употребляйте одно и то же слово так часто. Плюс никакого замещения здесь нет. Можно подобрать, например, слово "рассуждение", после которого будет следовать двоеточие.

Также есть аналогичная форма:

**Если есть следствие в виде: "x есть (это) y, *из-за*  z", — то формируется новое следствие вида "x не z, следовательно не y".**

Comment: Спасибо! Но там не "поэтому z", а именно "вследствие z", то есть "в силу z". Иными словами, "x есть y, потому что z".

Comment: Я понимаю, что не надо употреблять одни и те же слова часто, но в некоторых случаях это ведь допустимо. Например: "в том, кого мы любим, мы любим Бога и одновременно в Боге — наше высшее «я»".

Comment: Понял Вас. Лексический повтор иногда может употребляются, но здесь я **подчеркнул**, что **настолько** многочисленные употребление неуместно. А употребление слова **вследствие** я действительно не так воспринял. Сейчас исправлю ответ.

Comment: Ещё хотел бы добавить, что "вследствие" в данном случае неплохо бы употребить с сочетанием  "значения z".